# Handle MySQL DB unavailable in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that connects to multiple MySQL servers to provide reports. I would like to setup some sort of error handling that when one of these servers is unavailable my app it does not try to load those reports.

Comment: When you are not able to connect to mysql server, , your app only will not work because you will specify database name and the ip address for the same so it end up with triggering exception so your app only  will not work. In the model level you are trying to connect to mysql server you can do with Exception handling.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to setup the exception handling?